# Show a menu bar created in another class/file

Tags: java, swing

I have two files/class, the main class and the menubar class.

This is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    journalFrame = new JFrame("Journal Viewer");
    journalFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar = new JMenuBar());

    journalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    journalFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 800));
    journalFrame.pack();
    journalFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    journalFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is my menubar class:

```
MenuBar(){
    mMbar = new JMenuBar();

    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");

    openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    openItem.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    fileMenu.add(openItem);

    exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exitItem.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    fileMenu.add(exitItem);

    mMbar.add(fileMenu);
}
```

My output is just a plain window with no menubar. How do I make it appear?

Comment: `journalFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar = new MenuBar().mbar);`

Comment: *"I have .. class, .. menubar class."* Why is that in its own class? Creating it within the GUI class would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an object of your class, you're simply creating a `JMenuBar` object when you call `menuBar = new JMenuBar()`. Also if this is your full code it's got mutliple issues and honestly I can't be bothered to figure out why I'm getting compiler errors on dots and semicolons. Note that `setJMenuBar(JMenuBar menuBar)` can only be called with a JMenuBar object as parameter. So either `Override` that method to have it behave the way you want, or try something else.

I will join @AndrewThompson in his opinion that it would make a lot more sense to just create the menubar within the GUI class.

Here's what your code could (or maybe should) look like:

```java
public class Main
{
    private static JFrame journalFrame;
    private static JMenuBar menuBar;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        journalFrame = new JFrame("Journal Viewer");
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");

        JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        openItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // TODO: Your open action
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(openItem);

        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // TODO: Your exit action
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(aboutMenu);

        journalFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        journalFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        journalFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 800));
        journalFrame.pack();
        journalFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        journalFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```